# ImageView doesn't fill the height of its layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I wish to add an `ImageView` inside a `ListView`. I would like the image to fill the layout without distorsion (basically, fill the height and adapt its width).

This is what I get now:

[image]

I have put a grey background to the `ImageView` to make it easier to see. In red, it's the size I wish to get.

Here is my code:

**Project_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/name_project"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="25dp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_project"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="  details  "
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagesstep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**method getView() of my `Adapter`** :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {            
    View row = convertView;            
    if (row==null) {       
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_form, parent, false);
    }   
    TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name_project); 
    text.setText(this.objects[position].getName());       
    int IDImage=this.objects[position].getIDImage();       
    int IDPlay = this.objects[position].getIDPlay();
    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(IDImage, 0, 0, 0);         
    text.setCompoundDrawablePadding(7);    
    ImageView image = (ImageView)
    row.findViewById(R.id.imagesstep);                
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
    image.setImageResource(IDPlay);
    if (position == selectedPosition) {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8000ff00"));
    }  
    else {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    return row;
}
```

I tried to play with different parameters such as `ScaleType`, android:adjustViewBounds and layout_width but the height of my image never changed. I also tried to do it programatically (something like image.setMinHeight(parent.getHeight()) but it failed too.

Could anyone point me out what is going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `RelativeLayout` of the `layout_height` to `fill_parent`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView ... />

    <Button .. />

    <ImageView ... />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively you could set the `minHeight` attribute of the `ImageView` to `?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight`

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting both width and height to "?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from your imageview